# How to pass a AJAX call on OctoberCMS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, octobercms

Im using OctoberCMS, the user plugin and I want to send data via AJAX to a controller and save the data in the database (in the column of the logged in user).

So I created a new Route in my **routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('saveHighscore', 'test\Profile\Controllers\HighScore@saveHighscore')
->middleware('web');
```

And a controller

```
<?php
namespace Test\Profile\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use October\Rain\Auth\Models\User;
use RainLab\User\Facades\Auth;

class HighScore extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller
{
function saveHighscore(Request $request) {
    DB::table('users')->where(['id' => Auth::getUser()->id])->update(['highscore' => $request]);
}
}
```

And my jQuery calls

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "/saveHighscore",
        type: "POST",
        data: highscore
    });
```

But nothing works. If I call /saveHighscore in my browser with dummy data in the controller, it works fine

Comment: have a look at the build in ajax framework https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work without any issue.

But I think you are making 2 different requests

> In `ajax config` you specified -> `type: "POST"` and you are listening for `get` request

May be you just need to change `Route::get -> Route::post`

Now it should work expected.

If any doubts please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX framework only works on the CMS controller or Backend controllers (controllers extending backend/classes/controller). If you're wanting to send data via AJAX without using the built in AJAX framework, then we would have to see more information from your console / network tab of your browser dev tools to see why exactly it's failing.